# Declarative Navigation using AutoRoute in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bloc, flutter-provider, auto-route

I'm trying to implement declarative navigation in my Flutter app using the `AutoRoute` package. I have a complex navigation structure defined in my `AppRouter` class, and I'm using the `AuthCubit` for managing user authentication status. I would like to achieve declarative navigation based on the user's authentication status using `AutoRoute`.

auth_cubit.dart:

```
part 'auth_state.dart';

part 'auth_cubit.freezed.dart';

@injectable
class AuthCubit extends Cubit<AuthState> {
  final AuthStateRepository _authStateRepository;
  StreamSubscription<bool>? _authSubscription;

  AuthCubit(this._authStateRepository) : super(const AuthState.isLoggedIn()) {
    _init();
  }

  void _init() {
    _authSubscription =
        _authStateRepository.isUserLoggedIn.listen((isLoggedIn) {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        emit(const AuthState.isLoggedIn());
      } else {
        emit(const AuthState.isLoggedOut());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _authSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

auth_state.dart:

```
part of 'auth_cubit.dart';

@freezed
class AuthState with _$AuthState {
  const factory AuthState.isLoggedIn() = _IsLoggedIn;
  const factory AuthState.isLoggedOut() = _IsLoggedOut;
}
```

auth_state_repository.dart:

```
  @lazySingleton
  class AuthStateRepository {

    final BehaviorSubject<bool> _isUserLoggedIn = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

    void setUserLoggedIn(bool isLoggedIn) {
      _isUserLoggedIn.add(isLoggedIn);
    }
    Stream<bool> get isUserLoggedIn => _isUserLoggedIn.stream;
  }
```

token_repository.dart:

```
@singleton
class TokenRepository {
  TokenRepository(this._authStateRepository) {
    _init();
  }

  void _init() {
    _checkForAccessToken();
    _checkForRefreshToken();
  }

  final AuthStateRepository _authStateRepository;

  String? _accessToken;
  String? _refreshToken;

  //get refresh token
  FutureOr<String?> get refreshToken async {
    if (_refreshToken != null) {
      return _refreshToken;
    }
    return readRefreshToken().then((token) {
      _refreshToken = token;
      return token;
    });
  }

  //get access token
  FutureOr<String?> get accessToken async {
    if (_accessToken != null) {
      return _accessToken;
    }
    return readAccessToken().then((token) {
      _accessToken = token;
      return token;
    });
  }

  //check if token is expired
  Future<bool> tokenIsExpired() async {
    final token = await readAccessToken();
    return token == null || token.isEmpty;
  }

  //load token from secure storage
  Future<void> loadAccessToken() async {
    final token = await readAccessToken();
    if (token != null) {
      _accessToken = token;
    }
  }

  //load refresh token from secure storage
  Future<void> loadRefreshToken() async {
    final token = await readRefreshToken();
    if (token != null) {
      _refreshToken = token;
    }
  }

  //check if refresh token exists
  Future<bool> _hasRefreshToken() async {
    final token = await readRefreshToken();
    return token != null && token.isNotEmpty;
  }

  Future<void> _checkForRefreshToken() async {
    _hasRefreshToken().then((hasToken) {
      _authStateRepository.setUserLoggedIn(hasToken);
    });
  }

  //check if access token exists
  Future<bool> _hasAccessToken() async {
    final token = await readAccessToken();
    return token != null && token.isNotEmpty;
  }

  Future<void> _checkForAccessToken() async {
    _hasAccessToken().then((hasToken) {
      _authStateRepository.setUserLoggedIn(hasToken);
    });
  }

  //read refresh token from secure storage
  Future<String?> readRefreshToken() async {
    try {
      const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
      return secureStorage.read(key: _refreshTokenKey);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  //read access token from secure storage
  Future<String?> readAccessToken() async {
    try {
      const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
      return secureStorage.read(key: _accessTokenKey);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  //save refresh token to secure storage
  Future<bool> saveRefreshToken(String? token) async {
    try {
      const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
      await secureStorage.write(
        key: _refreshTokenKey,
        value: token,
      );
      _refreshToken = token;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //save access token to secure storage
  Future<bool> saveAccessToken(String? token) async {
    try {
      const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
      await secureStorage.write(
        key: _accessTokenKey,
        value: token,
      );
      _accessToken = token;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> refreshAccessToken() async {
    if (await tokenIsExpired()) {
      final refreshToken = await readRefreshToken();
      final accessToken = await readAccessToken();
      if (refreshToken != null && accessToken != null) {
          final response = await getIt<ApiDatasource>().refreshToken(
            UseTokenModel(accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken),
          );
          final newAccessToken = response.accessToken;

          await saveAccessToken(newAccessToken);

          _accessToken = newAccessToken;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

token_interceptor.dart:

```
@injectable
class TokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final TokenRepository _tokenRepository;


  TokenInterceptor(this._tokenRepository);

  @override
  Future<void> onRequest(
      RequestOptions options,
      RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
      ) async {
    final String? token = await _tokenRepository.accessToken;
    if (token != null) {
      options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    }
    handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onError(
      DioException err,
      ErrorInterceptorHandler handler,
      ) async {
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 || err.response?.statusCode == 403) {
      _tokenRepository.refreshAccessToken();
    }
    handler.next(err);
  }
}
```

I want to conditionally navigate users based on their authentication status. For example, if a user is logged in, they should be directed to the `DashboardRoute` page. If they are not logged in, they should be directed to the `LoginRoute page`.

How can I achieve declarative navigation in this setup? Should I modify my `AppRouter` or my `AuthCubit`? Can you provide an example of how to conditionally navigate users using the `AutoRoute` package?

**Thank you in advance for your help!**

Feel free to ask for more details in comments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone encounters same problem as mine, here is a solution.

I've made `AuthWrapperPage` that wraps `auth` and `dashboard` pages in `AppRouter`:

```
part 'app_router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig()
@lazySingleton
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          page: AuthWrapperRoute.page,
          initial: true,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              page: DashboardRoute.page,
              children: [
                AutoRoute(page: AdoptionRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: FavoritePetsRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: MissingPetsRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: MyPetsRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: MessagesRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: SettingsRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: SubmissionsRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: MissingRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: VolunteeringRoute.page),
              ],
            ),
            AutoRoute(
              page: AuthRoute.page,
              children: [
                AutoRoute(page: LoginRoute.page,),
                AutoRoute(page: RegisterRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: PasswordResetEmailRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: PasswordResetRoute.page),
                AutoRoute(page: PasswordResetSuccessRoute.page),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ];
}
```

here is the wrapper class:

```
@RoutePage()
class AuthWrapperPage extends StatelessWidget implements AutoRouteWrapper {
  AuthWrapperPage({super.key});

  final AuthCubit authCubit = getIt<AuthCubit>();
  final AuthStateRepository authStateRepository = getIt<AuthStateRepository>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: AutoRouter.declarative(routes: (_) {
            return [
              state.map(
                isLoggedIn: (_) {
                  return const AdoptionRoute();
                },
                isLoggedOut: (_) {
                  return const LoginRoute();
                },
              )
            ];
          }),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget wrappedRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<AuthCubit>(
          create: (context) => authCubit,
        ),
      ],
      child: this,
    );
  }
}
```

I've used the `blocProvider` and `blocbuilder`, inside the `AutoRouter.declarative` I've mapped the states to the routes that I want navigate to.
Here is updated `TokenInterceptor`

```
   @injectable
    class TokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {
      final TokenRepository _tokenRepository;


      TokenInterceptor(this._tokenRepository);

      @override
      Future<void> onRequest(
          RequestOptions options,
          RequestInterceptorHandler handler,
          ) async {
        final String? token = await _tokenRepository.accessToken;
        if (token != null) {
          options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
        }
        handler.next(options);
      }

      @override
      Future<void> onError(
          DioException err,
          ErrorInterceptorHandler handler,
          ) async {
        if (err.response?.statusCode == 401 || err.response?.statusCode == 403) {
          _tokenRepository.refreshAccessToken();
        }
        handler.next(err);
      }

      @override
      Future<void> onResponse(
          Response response,
          ResponseInterceptorHandler handler,
          ) async {
        final responseBody = response.data as Map<String, dynamic>?;
        if (responseBody != null) {
          final String? accessToken = responseBody['accessToken'] as String?;
          final String? refreshToken = responseBody['refreshToken'] as String?;
          if (accessToken != null) {
            _tokenRepository.saveAccessToken(accessToken);
            _tokenRepository.recheckForAccessToken();
          }
          if (refreshToken != null) {
            _tokenRepository.saveRefreshToken(refreshToken);
          }
        }
        handler.next(response);
      }
    }
```

now when I make call to the API the onResponse method gets access and refresh tokens and saves them to the `SecureStorage`, when you reopen the app `tokenReposiitory` init function checks if the token is saved to the `SecureStorage`, if it is the initial screen will be `adoptionPage` if any call will return response code 401 or 403 the `refreshToken` will be called.